# Reading the first row value of an Excel File

Tags: javascript, excel

I am new in Angular, now I am trying to get the value of the first row of an excel file and save it in the "range" variable, but I always receive the same value ("Nan"), I am not sure what I am doing worst. If someone can give me a handle I will appreciated it, thanks

```
 var files = event.target.files;
var file = files[0];
this.fileName = file.name;

var wbName = new FileReader();
wbName.onload = (e: any) => {
  const bstr: string = e.target.result;
  const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary' });
  this.workbookName = wb.SheetNames[0];
  const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[this.workbookName];
  var range = XLSX.utils.decode_row('A1');
  console.log('TEST', range);

};
wbName.readAsBinaryString(file);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this code will help you. Printing every row., though it's not angular

```
reader.onload = function(e) {
  var data = e.target.result;
  var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'binary'});

  workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
    // Here is your object
    var XL_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
    var json_object = JSON.stringify(XL_row_object);
    console.log(json_object);

  })

};

reader.onerror = function(ex) {
  console.log(ex);
};

reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
```